# c# httpwebrequest for basic authentication

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, basic-authentication

I've been trying to use a username, password and access key to authenticate on a server, so that I could use its API. I used to following code:

```
        string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("myusername:mypass"));      
        string api = "blahblahblahblabh";
        string auth_string = "Basic " + encoded;
        string _post_string = "username=myusername&password=mypass&grant_type=password";
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(https_website) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Accept = "application/xml";
        request.Method = "POST";            
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-forms-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = _post_string.Length;
        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer = cookies;

        request.Headers["Authorization"] = auth_string;
        request.Headers["api-key"] = api;
        request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender1, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
        writer.Write(_post_string);
        writer.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        string xml_response = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
```

So I sent a POST request with the username/password and access_key and tried to receive a response. I always get "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found". If I add more to the string of the 1st line, for example if instead of "myusername:mypass" I use "myusername:mypass:password" I get an error 401 (Unauthorized). I don't understand why this is happening...

Comment: winforms is irrelevant here

Comment: 402 is not "Unauthorized", did you mean 401?

Comment: @Crowcoder You're right! It's 401...

Comment: I don't have an explanation, but it seems strange that you use both Basic auth and POST your credentials in the body.

Comment: @Crowcoder I'm not familiar with this procedure. I just copied code from the internet and adapted it to my situation. If I comment out the streamwriter and the contentlength property, the result is still the same...

Comment: You have to know what the server expects so you can craft the request appropriately. Sounds like you are guessing?

Comment: @Crowcoder I'm not... The server is supposed to expect 3 parameters (username, password, grant_type) and 3 (or 4, I'll explain) headers (Content-Type, Accept and Authorization (with Basic authentication)). The 4th header has to include the access key. I used api-key as its name after detecting an authentication from another application (by using Fiddler).

Comment: No clue, does this service have a support department?

Comment: @Crowcoder They do... Stackoverflow is faster :)  The documentation is scarce... So, is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me except that the username and password are used in both the message body and basic auth  header.

Comment: @Crowcoder Btw do you have any idea why the access key (which consists of numbers and letters only) gives an exception when trying to set the header "Authorization"?  ("Specified value has invalid control characters"). I had to encode and decode it to be accepted...